# html5 file doesn't show turkish characters as properly

Tags: html, jsp, turkish

I am in trouble with turkişh character on html5. I investigated same issues on web and I applied solutions but it doesn't works. I share my codes. Could you help me please?

here is my allemployees.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="<c:url value="../resources/css/bootstrap.css" />"    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="../resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="table-responsive">
<h2>Tüm Çalışanlar</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<tr>
<td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
<label>TC No</label>
</td>
<td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
<label>Ad</label>
</td>
<td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
<label>Soyad</label>
</td>
<td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
<label>Başlama Tarihi</label>
</td>
<td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
<label>Maaş</label>
</td>
</tr>
</div>
</div>
<c:forEach items="$(allEmployees)" var="employee">
<tr>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<td>$(employee.citizenNumber)</td>
<td>$(employee.name)</td>
<td>$(employee.surname)</td>
<td>$(employee.joiningDate)</td>
<td>$(employee.salary)</td>
<td>
<a href="<c:url value='/edit-${employee.oid}-employee' />">${employee.oid}</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="<c:url value='/delete-${employee.oid}-employee' />">delete</a>
</td>
</div>
</div>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</div>
<br/>
<a href="<c:url value='/new' />">Yeni Çalışan</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my jsp file(I include the html):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ include file="../templates/allemployees.html" %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `import` with `charEncoding` attribute in JSTL core lib.

```
<c:import url="../templates/allemployees.html" charEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

**EDIT**

If you put html files into *WEB-INF/templates* then you should use mapping

**xml**:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/templates/**" location="/WEB-INF/templates/"  />
```

**annotation**: add addResourceHandlers method in Config class

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
   registry.addResourceHandler("/templates/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/templates/");
}
```

so, you can access html file in `WEB-INF` folder like this:

`<c:import url="/templates/allemployees.html" charEncoding="UTF-8" />`

Comment: I tried this but Spring MVC give this error No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sample/WEB-INF/templates/allemployees.html]

Comment: edited answer @luffy, web-inf folder isn't accessed directly.

Comment: thank you but I use Spring 4 MVC I didn't use xml for configurations I handle it anotation. So do you know how to handle this on anotation?

Comment: I investigated your edited. I want to ask one thing. My template directory under the webapp/resources directory and jsp page under the WEB-INF/pages. I added webapp/resources directory to Resource Handler. And I tried your solution but I failed. Spring give an error no mapping found for allemployees.html.

Comment: @luffy for /webapp/resources/template/allempoyees.html, try addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resource/") and url="/resources/templates/allemployees.html". And You can use this for other static files too, e.g href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />" will map your bootstrap file.

Comment: yes it work's for html and turkish character and I clicked your answer thank you so much. but now I can not include bootstrap files to allemployees.html. I did like you said <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet"> on allemployees.html <head></head> tags but it doesn't work.

Comment: @luffy sorry, I think you use bootstrap in JSP head tag, you cannot use JSTL (c:url etc.) in plain html but JSP.

Comment: Ok I got it. I'll try this. <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>